# How do I find and read lines from text files? Batch

Tags: batch-file, find

I need some thing read in a text file that goes as follows:

---

Nicholas password1

Micheal password2

myname password3

---

I want the batch file to detect if the variable %fname% (Nicholas) exists.
after that, I need it to find out if %pword%(password1) is after %fname%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `for` command like this:

```
set AUTH_OK=0

for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a in (passwords.txt) do (
    if "%%a"=="%fname%" (
        if "%%b"=="%pword%" (
            set AUTH_OK=1
        )
    )
)

if %AUTH_OK%==1 (
    echo Access granted.
) else (
    echo Access denied.
)
```

That's assuming you do this in a batch file.  If you do it from the command line you have to use a single `%` on those loop variables instead of double (`%%`).

I should mention that this is case-sensitive.

Comment: could this be two separate codes? I mean that (and I should have been more specific)it tests for %fname% than at another time, %pword%. other than this, your answer was very useful, I am using batch, and I know nothing about the FOR command.

Comment: Yeah, just use one or the other of those individual if-statements.  You'll see I've nested them because I want both conditions to be true (there is no 'AND' operator in batch files).  To find out more about the `for` command, type `for /?` on the command line.